# Is it possible to make Chrome open bookmarks in the same tab from chrome://bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome

In `chrome://bookmarks/`, I don't see a convenient way of opening a bookmark in the same tab. It always opens a new window or tab. One solution I confirmed to work was copying the bookmark URL using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> or right click menu and pasting it in the addresss bar but this is slightly cumbersome compared to just double clicking. Is it possible to open in the same tab without using this method or the bookmark bar?

Comment: Have you tried using extensions like this one : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-link-in-same-tab/kgpefningcojblgciiljmabggbbjiojb?hl=en#:~:text=Also%20adds%20an%20%22Open%20link,down%20instead%20of%20clicking%20them.

Comment: @Madhubala I had a try just then and they still open in a new tab.